# Duistermaat and Kolk's lost chapters on Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, books

In Duistermaat and Kolk's book *Lie Groups*, it is written in the preface that "the text contains references to chapters belonging to a future volume". I could not find this second volume anywhere. Has it been published? Is it available somewhere?

For example, on page 51, they refer to Chapter 14, while the book only has 4 chapters. I would be very much interested to read these additional chapters.

[image: Lie groups]

Comment: Johan Kolk's own [web site](https://www.uu.nl/medewerkers/JACKolk/0) does not list a volume 2. It gives his email, you might ask him?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I tried more than a year ago, but he never replied.

Comment: It seems a bit like the late John Horváth's mythical second volume of "Topological Vector Spaces and Distributions I"...

Comment: More exceptionnal is the book "Topologie, t.2" of Gustave Choquet Masson 1964. The first volume was never written.

Comment: Reed-Simon's "Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics I-IV" was supposed to have seven volumes, and there are several references to chapters in volumes V-VII within, but the latter never appeared.

Answer (score 8):

I was the last PhD student of Duistermaat, and I'm pretty sure there is no second volume. I also don't remember Hans Duistermaat speaking of working on a second volume.

The last textbook that Duistermaat and Kolk completed was [Distributions](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4675-2), published in 2010.

Comment: There’s got to have been at least a manuscript: as OP hints at, the published book has dozens of forward references to later chapters (5: root systems; 9: cohomology; 10: Haar measure; 11: group actions; 14: algebraic groups).

Comment: There is even a case where a *definition* only appears in the 2nd volume but is used in the first: p.113 "Here $\lambda$ is a diffeomorphism from an open neighborhood of the diagonal in $M\times M$ to an open neighborhood of the zero section of $TM$, as defined in Lemma 11.1.1".